# CSS dropdown is not opening on first click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a drop-down menu in pure HTML, CSS and JavaScript. It should work such that whenever I click on a specified button, the dropdown should open.

However, when I click on the button for the first time, it does not open. When I click on it after the first click, it works fine.

I have attached a code snippet for better understanding.

```js
function showDrp() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");
    var drpbutn = document.getElementById("drpbutn");
      if (dropdown.style.display === "none") {
        dropdown.style.display = "block";
        drpbutn.innerHTML = "DROPDOWN &#x25B4;";
      } else {
        dropdown.style.display = "none";
        drpbutn.innerHTML = "DROPDOWN &#x25BE;";
      }
}
```

```css
.upper-cont {
  width: 30%; 
  height: 30%;
  position: absolute; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  background-color: blue; 
  color: white; 
  text-align: center;
}
     
.upper-cont:hover { background-color: #dfdfdf; color: blue;}

.dropdown {
  background-color: #4A4A4A;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div class="upper-cont" style="margin-left: 40%;" onclick="showDrp()"><h3 id="drpbutn">DROPDOWN &#x25BE;</h3></div>

<div class="dropdown" id="dropdown">This is a dropdown</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial value of `dropdown.style.display` was not equal to `"none"`, and because the script treats anything other than `"none"` as visible, the initial state of the dropdown was treated as if the dropdown was already shown.

A simple way to fix this, is to modify the if condition:

```js
function showDrp() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");
    var drpbutn = document.getElementById("drpbutn");
      if (dropdown.style.display !== "block") {
        dropdown.style.display = "block";
        drpbutn.innerHTML = "DROPDOWN &#x25B4;";
      } else {
        dropdown.style.display = "none";
        drpbutn.innerHTML = "DROPDOWN &#x25BE;";
      }
}
```

```css
.upper-cont {
  width: 30%; 
  height: 30%;
  position: absolute; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  background-color: blue; 
  color: white; 
  text-align: center;
}
     
.upper-cont:hover { background-color: #dfdfdf; color: blue;}

.dropdown {
  background-color: #4A4A4A;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div class="upper-cont" style="margin-left: 40%;" onclick="showDrp()"><h3 id="drpbutn">DROPDOWN &#x25BE;</h3></div>

<div class="dropdown" id="dropdown">This is a dropdown</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thankyou do much! I was in this problem for many days, and now my problem is solved!

Answer (score -1):

This is pretty easy with jQuery. Please Try this solution

```js
  function showDrp() {        
     $("#dropdown").toggle();
     $("#drpbutn span").toggleClass("caret-up");
          }
```

```css
   .upper-cont {
      width: 30%; 
      height: 30%;
      position: absolute; 
      cursor: pointer; 
      background-color: blue; 
      color: white; 
      text-align: center;
    }
         
    .upper-cont:hover { background-color: #dfdfdf; color: blue;}

    .dropdown {
      background-color: #4A4A4A;
      color: white;
      position: fixed;
      top: 30%;
      left: 0%;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50%;
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
   <html>
    <body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <div class="upper-cont" style="margin-left: 40%;" onclick="showDrp()"><h3 id="drpbutn">DROPDOWN <span class="caret"></span></h3></div>

    <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown">This is a dropdown</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This solution is also nice, but I had written in my question that I am using plain HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Also, in your solution, the hexadecimal code is shown on the button instead of the symbol.

Comment: Oh, sorry the problem you had with my solution. you can upvote you think this could be useful for others. thanks

Comment: Thankyou, I have upvoted your answer. However, it was downvoted previously, so it is showing that the votes are "0".